# formatted fixed length double in java

Tags: java

I want to format the output of values of double datatype
to fixed length. I used the following code but got some errors during the execution of the program.

Here is what I've tried:

```
double p = 80.00;
double r = 199999.00;
double n = 80.00;

System.out.printf("║%9.2f│%9.f│%9.2f│%9.2f║", p ,r ,n , p * (1 + r) * n);
```

I want to get this output:

```
║    80.00│199999.000000│    80.00│1280000000.00║
```

Can anyone help me to get this type of output ? 
I used this for creating a table of raw and calculated values.

Comment: what kind of error are you getting?

Comment: errors are shown to you to read it, not to ignore it...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you are missing number in %9.f│, so it should be like

```
System.out.printf("║%9.2f│%9.2f│%9.2f│%9.2f║", p ,r ,n , p * (1 + r) * n);
```

Comment: here is how your code should look like:System.out.printf("║%9.2f│%9.2f│%9.2f│%9.2f║", p ,r ,n , p * (1 + r) * n);

Comment: @SahyogVishwakarma if you found a working solution, then mark it as the accepted answer, so this question doesnt keep showing up in the unanswered category.

Answer (score 1):

You have bug in your code, it should be:

```
System.out.printf("║%9.2f│%9f│%9.2f│%9.2f║", p ,r ,n , p * (1 + r) * n)
```

I tested it with below code:

```
double p = 80.00;
double r = 199999.00;
double n = 80.00;
System.out.printf("║%9.2f│%9f│%9.2f│%9.2f║", p ,r ,n , p * (1 + r) * n);
```

The result should look like:

```
║    80.00│199999.000000│    80.00│1280000000.00║
```

Comment: thnx #tmucha for your response. My issue with my code has been resolved by the answer given by #Adi